# Is it OK to use lag=1 for Granger causality test?

Tags: feature-selection, model-selection, vector-autoregression, lags, granger-causality

I have a question related to Granger Causality testing.

Is it okay to use a lag-length of `lag=1` in my Granger-test? The optimum lag length selection in my R `VARselect(data,lag=maxlag,type=trend)` model says that `lag=1` shows the best and most stable information criteria values according to AIC, BIC and FPE.

I have a 30-year set of quarterly data and I'm using a `maxlag` of 4.

Answer (score 2):

If your data is stationary, then yes, based on the information you provided it seems OK to use $\text{lag}=1$.

If your data is nonstationary, you should follow Toda-Yamamoto procedure described very explicitly and clearly in Dave Giles' [blog post](http://davegiles.blogspot.ca/2011/04/testing-for-granger-causality.html). There are certain important points to pay attention to with respect to lag order selection under cointegrated data (see especially basic steps 5. and 8. of the Toda-Yamamoto procedure in the above source).

Comment: I see. And "lag=1" essentially also means that the effect is delayed by "1" time unit, at least when I find p<0.05?

Comment: The answer is a little tricky. If the contemporaneous correlation matrix of model errors is diagonal, then yes. If not, you may have an alternative representation of the model, a structural VAR (SVAR), where there are also contemporaneous effects.